# GeoExt: Excluding some of the layers from the legend

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, legend

Openlayers and GeoExt for producing a web map. The map has a legend panel generated by GeoExt. By default, GeoExt grabs the details of every layers from the map and create a legend for all the layers. However, I would like to exclude some of the layers to be displayed from the legend, what should I do to achieve this?

```
    legendPanel = new GeoExt.LegendPanel({
    map: map,
    title: 'Legend Panel',
    renderTo:'description',
    border: false,
    autoScroll: true,
    defaults: {
        style: 'padding:5px',           
        baseParams: {
            FORMAT: 'image/png',
            LEGEND_OPTIONS: 'forceLabels:on;fontName=Verdana;fontSize:11'
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually quite detailed documentation about the issue [here](http://geoext.org/lib/GeoExt/widgets/LegendPanel.html). Here's some quotes from the site relating to your issue.

> The LegendPanel will include legends for all the layers in the layerStore it is configured with, unless the layer is configured with displayInLayerSwitcher: false, or a layer record has a hideInLegend field with a value of true. Additional filtering can be done by configuring a filter on the LegendPanel.

Here is my guessing code that applies the filter function:

```
    legendPanel = new GeoExt.LegendPanel({
    map: map,
    title: 'Legend Panel',
    renderTo:'description',
    border: false,
    autoScroll: true,
    filter: function(record){
        //Your filter function goes here, note that the function is processed on each layer.
        // Return false for those layers you want to exclude.
    },
    defaults: {
        style: 'padding:5px',           
        baseParams: {
            FORMAT: 'image/png',
            LEGEND_OPTIONS: 'forceLabels:on;fontName=Verdana;fontSize:11'
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Where in the code shall I apply the filter setting? I tried something like this but it is not working: `legendPanel = new GeoExt.LegendPanel({
  map: map,
  title: 'Legend Panel',
  renderTo:'description',
  border: false,
  autoScroll: true,
  defaults: {
   showTitle: false,
   style: 'padding:5px',   
   baseParams: {
    FORMAT: 'image/png',
    LEGEND_OPTIONS: 'forceLabels:on;fontName=Verdana;fontSize:11'
   }
  },
  loader: {
   filter: function(record) {
    return record.get("layer").name.indexOf("locals") !== -1
        }
    }`

Comment: Never used GeoExt before, but I paste my guessing code to apply filter function. Hope it helps.

Comment: Glad I could help